# Is there a javascript graph drawing library that does balloon tree layouts?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, graph-layout, graph-drawing, information-visualization

Wikipedia's entry says balloon tree layouts are one of the common types, but I can't find any javascript drawing library that seems to support it out of the box. Am I missing one? A cheap or open source Flex/ActionScript library works too. I don't really know anything about graph drawing. Would it be easy to use an algorithm from a paper with d3.js or something?

Comment: Is [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) not the kind of balloon tree you're looking for?

Comment: No, I know about forced directed layouts. In balloon layouts each node's children should be laid out circularly in approximately even arc segments: http://lab.kapit.fr/display/visualizationlayouts/Balloon+layout

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a balloon layout for d3 for my uni honours project. Its currently in my d3 fork, but I'm hoping to send a pull request upstream some time after the honours rush (provided the d3 folks want it). Its definitely still a work-in-progress and in need of review, but [here](https://github.com/justinvdm/d3/blob/add-balloon-layout/src/layout/balloon.js) it is.

You can check out [this](http://bl.ocks.org/3676778) bl.ock of mine that uses it.

Comment: I've just noticed 8 years later that someone answered this. The bl.ock doesn't seem to display anything tho and the github link 404s